# Is it a bad practice to send raw SharePoint Http requests inside our power automate flows using "Send http request to SharePoint" action

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, flow, microsoft-graph

I want to start a complex and lengthy Power automate flow.  which contain actions that do not have relevant Power automate built-in actions, those operations include:-

- Create a sharing links for anonymous users using passwords
- Create a sharing link for external users and get the sharing link inside the workflow to build an html table of all the sharing links and send them all at once.
- Breaking Permission inheritance of an item and of a document
- Fetching all Permission assignments of an item and of a document
- Removing all Permission assignments of an item and of a document
- Reset Role inheritance of an item and of a document

So the only option I have is to send HTTP requests to SharePoint using "Send HTTP request to SharePoint" action to implement the above functionalities:

[image]

Now based on my reading is that Microsoft is considering SharePoint API as a legacy API and it is advising us to use the Graph APIs instead. but i am facing an issue, is that currently (as of May 2023) Microsoft graph API does not support all of my above operations on items and documents. so this led me to ask myself, will I be doing things correctly (and in a recommended way) by implementing all the above functionalities using "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint"? and what other approaches I can have which are more recommended and more future-proof?

Comment: It is safe to use SharePoint REST API and "Send HTTP request to SharePoint" action in flow. SharePoint REST APIs are not going anywhere and will not be deprecated anytime soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to use SharePoint REST API and "Send HTTP request to SharePoint" action in Power automate flows.

SharePoint REST APIs are not going anywhere and will not be deprecated anytime soon.

There are so many different types of operations which are not yet supported by Microsoft Graph but are supported by using SharePoint REST APIs.

**For example**: Breaking SharePoint list item permissions is not yet possible using Microsoft graph but it is possible using SharePoint REST APIs.

Also, SharePoint REST APIs are specific to SharePoint operations while Microsoft Graph APIs has endpoints across multiple Microsoft 365 services including SharePoint (limited endpoints as compared to SharePoint REST APIs).